# Upgrade google-api-java-client 10.3 to 15.0rc

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api-java-client

I'm using Google Api Java Client for login with Service Account (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts) to my application, but when I want to upgrade to 15.0rc (or 14.0) I have some problems:

On the line:

```
 GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
```

Eclipse says:

```
The type com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Adding:

```
google-api-client-1.15.0-rc.jar
google-oauth-client-1.15.0-rc.jar
google-http-client-1.15.0-rc.jar
```

Clean, rebuild... nothing work.

Any idea?

Comment: ever find a solution/

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error, resolved it with following version of google-api-client jar

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
```